# Map new object from two objects array angular typescript baesed on id

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, foreach

I have something like this

```
export class Question {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  answers: Answer[];
}

export class Answer {
  id: string;
  text: string;
  questionId: string;
}
```

and I have two object like this

```
answers =  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "some comment1",
      "questionId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "some comment2",
      "questionId": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "text": "some comment3",
      "questionId": 3
    }
  ];

questions = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Name1",
      "description": "typicode1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Name2",
      "description": "typicode2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Name3",
      "description": "typicode3"
    }
  ];

questionsAndAnswers: Question[];
```

Now i need to map answer to correct **question** on property **answers**

My new **questionsAndAnswers** should look like this

```
questionsAndAnswers = [{
      id: 1,
      title: Name1,
      description: typicode1;
      answers: [{
          "id": 1,
          "text": "some comment1",
          "questionId": 1
        }]
},
{
      id: 2,
      title: Name2,
      description: typicode2;
      answers: []
},
{
      id: 3,
      title: Name3,
      description: typicode3;
      answers: [{
          "id": 2,
          "text": "some comment2",
          "questionId": 3
        },
{
          "id": 3,
          "text": "some comment3",
          "questionId": 3
        }]
}
];
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked into using `.filter` on your answers array to get the answers to a particular question?

Comment: I dont even know how to start, Do i have to foreach question and then inside answers?

Answer (score 0):

You could try use Array [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function. Try the following

```js
var questions = [ { "id": 1, "title": "Name1", "description": "typicode1" }, { "id": 2, "title": "Name2", "description": "typicode2" }, { "id": 3, "title": "Name3", "description": "typicode3" } ];
var answers =  [ { "id": 1, "text": "some comment1", "questionId": 1 }, { "id": 2, "text": "some comment2", "questionId": 3 }, { "id": 3, "text": "some comment3", "questionId": 3 } ];
  
var questionsAndAnswers = questions.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  acc[index] = curr;
  acc[index].answers = answers.filter(answer => answer.questionId === curr.id);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(questionsAndAnswers);
```

Comment: This works great, i have never used reduce, thanks, can you make answer on map and foreach, that i can understand, because I need to learn, this is to complex for me :(

Comment: I'd say it's better to learn about the `reduce` function. It's available in almost all the major languages. It might be easier to begin by printing the variables `acc`, `curr` inside and seeing how it iterates over the array.